# Python Pytest : Import Error from a different directory

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

Both `c/src/c.py` and `m/src/m.py` use `auth/auth.py`. 
When I run the test case of `c/tests` with `python3 -m pytest` from within the tests folder, it works. 
But if I do the same with `m/tests/`, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auth'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You said `c/tests` and `m/tests/` , Here i can see `/` extra. Is this the issue?
May be it's your typing mistake here. If yes than please update the question!

Comment: How do you import auth ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing either auth folder name or rename auth.py

Comment: The auth.py naming is for the purpose of this question only. It is actually a Singleton logger class. Can you please explain why changing the name would help?

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help.